# I'm using placement new & virtual functions; why is my virtual function table wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class template that I'm using to 'wrap' several common types of containers. The goal is to replace

```
getItems( vector< ItemType > &x );
getItems( set< ItemType > &x );
getItems( my_custom_vector< ItemType > &x );
(...and several others...)
```

with a single function that looks like this:

```
getItems( Cont< ItemType > x );
```

A stripped-down implementation (I'll include only the code for vectors) currently looks like this:

```
template< class T > ContBase {
public:
   ContBase( void *container ) : mContainer( container ) {}
   virtual void add( const T& item ) = 0;
   virtual void clear() = 0;
protected:
   void *mContainer;
};

template< class T > ContVector : public ContBase< T > {
public:
   ContVector( std::vector< T > &native_container )
      : ContBase( (void *) &native_container ) {}
   void add( const T& item ) { vec().push_back(item); }
   void clear() { vec().clear(); }
protected:
   std::vector< T > &vec() { return *(std::vector< T > *) mContainer; }
};

template< class T > class Cont {
public:
   Cont( std::vector< T > &x ) { new (&mMem) ContVector< T >( x ); }
   void clear() { container()->clear(); }
   void add( const T& item ) { container()->add( item ); }
protected:
   ContBase< T > *container() { return (ContBase< T > *) &mMem[ 0 ]; }
   unsigned char mMem[ sizeof(ContBase< T >) ];
};
```

I did some initial testing, and it worked great in a controlled benchmark setup. The main tricky thing here, I think, is the *clever* use of that placement new in the constructor for Cont. However, once I stuck it in a real application (Visual Studio 2010 C++ Compiler) and ran whole-program optimization (w/ link-time code generation, optimize for speed, etc.), I started seeing serious problems. Specifically, I have a function like this:

```
void MyClass::myFunc( Index x, Cont< Index > container, uint r )
{
    // ... Return if x is invalid
    cerr << "VFPTR: " << (void*) ((uint *) ((void*) &verts))[0] << endl;
    container.add( x );
    // ...Potentially add some more things to container.
}
```

Which gives me output like this (note that the insane typecast is a hack to get the value of the virtual function table in VC++):

```
VFPTR: 0AD98708
// Repeat above line 17 times
VFPTR: 0018B830
```

Firstly, it seems very strange indeed that the virtual function pointer *can* be different. Secondly, it is annoying that this same code works in Debug mode; this only shows up when optimization is turned on. Thirdly, it's notable that the new pointer (0018B830) is a pointer to the virtual function table in the *base* class, ContBase. The crash then occurs when you call container.add(x), a NULL value.

So my core question here is: Is this legal code, or have I missed an undefined behavior case? Is Microsoft's compiler broken here, or is my code undefined to begin with?

Comment: I think you are massively overcomplicating things by using placement new, `void*`, etc.  Why not just make the function `getItems` a template parameterized over the argument?

Comment: Off-topic, but I think it's important: `unsigned char mMem[ sizeof(ContBase< T >) ];` will not be properly aligned for a `ContBase< T >`.

Comment: `ContBase<>` stores a _pointer_ to the `std::vector<>` passed in to the constructor; are you sure that `std::vector<>` is still alive at the point `MyClass::myFunc` is executing? If it was deleted or went out of scope then you've got simple object-lifetime-related UB here. (BTW, your implementation could be **greatly** simplified if you implemented `ContBase<>` in terms of [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/) rather than doing all this pointer/type erasure malarkey.)

Comment: templatetypedef: No, that won't work, because template functions must be fully implemented in the header file, whereas getItems() as written here can be in the CPP file. I get circular dependencies and compile-time issues if I move everything to the header files (this is part of a large project), and sometimes getItems is a very large function (so code bloat is an issue).

Comment: ildjarn: Object lifetime is not an issue with the way I'm using this class. The vector is owned by the function that calls getItems, since it is an output parameter; it is the caller's problem to ensure it's valid when it passes it in. Note that calls to getItems can take a vector reference directly because of Cont's constructor. (i.e. vector<int> x; getItems(x);). I'll take a closer look at boost's variant, though, that might be interesting (not sure I'm allowed to link in boost, however).

Comment: If you mean "link" in the literal sense, then it's worth noting that Boost.Variant is header-only, i.e., no linking required.

Comment: R. Martinho Fernandes: Hmm, that may well be relevant. I also tried doing it by making ContBase a non-pure-virtual class, then doing a placement new on top of it, but I was seeing strange issues with that as well.

Comment: @AHelps : Please prefix the names of the people you're addressing with `@` so that the comment will show up in their respective inboxes.

Comment: @ildjarn Ah, I don't use this enough >_<. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So, to try and address the alignment problem, I changed unsigned char mMem[]; to ContBase<T> mMem;, and changed the pure virtuals to empty functions. This did, in fact, fix the problem, but I feel like I don't understand it. I'll accept any answer that can explain it clearly enough for me to understand :).

Answer (score 0):

The main undefined behavior issue I see is that the (default) copy constructor and assignment operator of `Cont<T>` do a bytewise copy of the `ContVector<T>` object held in the mMem array.  Since `ContVector<T>` is not *trivially copyable* (see 9 and 3.9 in the C++ spec), this is undefined.  From your description of the exact issue you are seeing it seems like the optimizer is making assumption that it can reorder some operation with byte copy of the mMem array which results in you getting a copy of a partially constructed (or partially destructed) object.

So you might be able to make this work by adding a copy ctor and assignment operator that do the copy/assign properly rather than relying on bytewise copy of the mMem array.

Comment: How is ContVector<T> not trivially copyable? My desired copy behavior is pointer assignment (ContVector<> refers to an existing vector, it doesn't own it, and copies should refer to the same one). Unfortunately, the C++ spec is not online, so I can't look that section up offhand.

Comment: Sadly, this got auto-selected as the answer, but it is not correct. The desired behavior is indeed a bit-for-bit copy of mMem (ContVector<T> is POD). So if you come along later, please check the comments on the original question for a more accurate answer; this appears to have been an issue with byte alignment.